# MySQL Query Optimization with multiple Joins

Tags: php, mysql, join, query-optimization, explain

Hi guys I need some help!

I have some tables in mysql and need to join all of them to get the data, but I think this query could be faster than it is for now. That's why I did the "Explain" query and find something wrong their.

The query I do:

What I've read so far is that type = all is very bad, also that key is null, so these parts should be optimize. What's curious too, is that the id's by ref are all the same for some rows.

I guess I need to set Indexes to solve the problem or am I on the wrong way?

Edit:
Query:

Comment: 1. Your query is most likely against the sql standard because not all fields listed in the select list are in the group by list or are aggregated. 2. `limit` without order by is a bit pointless. 3. `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` disables `limit` optimisations.

Comment: Okay thanks for response. When we put the limit aside, grouped all listed fields in the group by statement...the outcome of the query would be as bad as the explain shows. So how can I fix that?

Comment: Somebody else maybe?

Comment: I'm waiting for the revised `SELECT` and `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: I edited the posting now with the recommend select + explain. Don't know why this should be helpful, but here you go :)